# Selecting a column from table based on value stored in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `#A` like this:

```
id  | main_value |  value1 |  Value2 |  value3 |    value4
------------------------------------------------------------
1   | VALUE1     |  1.00   |  0.00   |  0.00   |    2.00
2   | VALUE2     |  0.00   |  4.00   |  0.00   |    0.00
3   | VALUE4     |  0.00   |  0.00   |  1.00   |    5.00
4   | VALUE3     |  1.00   |  0.00   |  2.00   |    0.00
```

Each time only two values inserted in table (only two column from value1, value2, value3, value4)
I want to select only two values based on main value.
If my main value is `value1` then value of `1st` column is `values1` and the value of the `2nd` column is the other column which is non zero.

If my main value is `value2` then value of `1st` column is `values2` and the value of the `2nd` column is the other column which is non zero.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #A (id int, 
main_value Nvarchar(MAX), 
value1 DECIMAL(15,2), 
Value2 DECIMAL(15,2), 
value3 DECIMAL(15,2), 
value4 DECIMAL(15,2))

INSERT INTO #A VALUES(1, 'VALUE1',1,0,0,2 )
INSERT INTO #A VALUES(2, 'VALUE2',0,4,0,0 )
INSERT INTO #A VALUES(3, 'VALUE4',0,0,1,5 )
INSERT INTO #A VALUES(4, 'VALUE3',1,0,2,0 )

SELECT * FROM #A
```

Expected results:

```
id  | main_value |  1st    |  2nd    |  
--------------------------------------
1   | VALUE1     |  1.00   |  2.00   |
2   | VALUE2     |  4.00   |  1.00   |
3   | VALUE4     |  5.00   |  1.00   |
4   | VALUE3     |  2.00   |  1.00   |
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO #A VALUES(2, 'VALUE2',0,4,0,0 )` There should be a column with value = `1` ?

Comment: Kudos for showing sample data as DDL+DML as well as expected results. I wish there will come a day when this will not be a good enough reason to upvote a question - but it is not this day.

Answer (score 2):

Try below using case when

```
select id, main_value, 
case 
when main_value='VALUE1' then value1
when main_value='VALUE2' then value2
when main_value='VALUE4' then value4
when main_value='VALUE3' then value3
end as 1st,
case 
when main_value='VALUE1' then value2+value3+value4
when main_value='VALUE2' then value1+value3+value4
when main_value='VALUE4' then value1+value2+value3
when main_value='VALUE3' then value1+value2+value4
end as 2nd
from tablename
```

Comment: here i didnt know what is exact value of my main_column. it is not possible when i receive value5 in main_column.

Comment: @Thebeginner, can you please explain your problem more elaborately

Comment: Uh-oh. I think he is implying main_value could be value<any number>.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which database you are using, anyway for SQL Server such solution should work:

```
SELECT  id,
        main_value,
           COALESCE(NULLIF(value1,0)
                   ,NULLIF(value2,0)
                   ,NULLIF(value3,0)
                   ,NULLIF(value4,0)) as Value1

        , COALESCE(NULLIF(value4,0)
                   ,NULLIF(value3,0)
                   ,NULLIF(value2,0)
                   ,NULLIF(value1,0)) as Value2

FROM #A
```

If in database there are nulls instead of 0 then nullif function is unnecesssary. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this ? (it could be improved)

```
SELECT 
    id
,   main_value
,   CASE main_value
    WHEN 'VALUE1' THEN value1
    WHEN 'VALUE2' THEN Value2
    WHEN 'VALUE3' THEN value3
    WHEN 'VALUE4' THEN value4
    END [1st]
,   CASE main_value
    WHEN 'VALUE1' THEN COALESCE(Value2,value3,value4)
    WHEN 'VALUE2' THEN COALESCE(Value1,value3,value4)
    WHEN 'VALUE3' THEN COALESCE(Value1,value2,value4)
    WHEN 'VALUE4' THEN COALESCE(Value1,value2,value3)
    END [2st]   
FROM (
SELECT
    id
,   main_value
,   CASE WHEN value1 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE value1 END value1
,   CASE WHEN Value2 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Value2 END Value2
,   CASE WHEN value3 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE value3 END value3
,   CASE WHEN value4 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE value4 END value4
FROM #A
) D
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the `case` expression twice, you can use `cross apply`:

```
SELECT  id, main_value, [1st],
        value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 - [1st] As [2nd]    
FROM #A
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 
    CASE main_value  
        WHEN 'VALUE1' THEN value1
        WHEN 'VALUE2' THEN value2
        WHEN 'VALUE3' THEN value3
        WHEN 'VALUE4' THEN value4
    END As [1st]
) X
```